# Fast Way To Populate Many Formulas with Cell References

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a large spreadsheet of data and I'm writing a macro in VBA to populate another tab that duplicates the sheet with cell references not values (I realize this is odd but it's what I've been asked to do). The code I have here works but it takes FOREVER. I assume there must be a faster way since doing this by hand with the good ol ctrl cv takes less than a second.

```
Public Sub PopulateSheet()
Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim columnCounter As Long
Dim maxRow As Long

Set inputSheet = Sheets("inputSheet")
Set outputSheet = Sheets("outputSheet")

maxRow = inputSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With outputSheet
    For columnCounter = 1 To 6
        For rowCounter = 1 To maxRow
            .Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter).Formula = "=" & "'inputSheet'!" & Cells(rowCounter, columnCounter).Address
        Next rowCounter
    Next columnCounter
End With
```

Edit: I have already turned off screenupdating and set calculation to manual.

Comment: Set `ScreenUpdating` to False and `Application.Calculation` to manual before entering the loop.  Don't forget to reset Calculation when done - that setting is persistent.

Comment: I already have applied those ideas. I'll update the OP to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Public Sub PopulateSheet()
Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim columnCounter As Long
Dim maxRow As Long

Set inputSheet = Sheets("inputSheet")
Set outputSheet = Sheets("outputSheet")

maxRow = inputSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With outputSheet
    For columnCounter = 1 To 6

        .Cells(1, columnCounter).Formula = "=" & "'inputSheet'!" & Cells(1, columnCounter).Address(False,False)

        .Range(.Cells(1, columnCounter), .Cells(maxRow, columnCounter)).FillDown

    Next columnCounter
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set inputSheet = Sheets("inputSheet")
Set outputSheet = Sheets("outputSheet")

maxRow = inputSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row

inputsheet.Range("A1").resize(maxRow, 6).copy

With outputSheet
    .activate
    .range("A1").select
    .paste Link:=true
End With
```